# Running multiple custom packages from Weka command line

Tags: command-line, weka

I'm running WEKA from the unix command line.  I want to encase an alternating decision tree (ADTree) within a Rotation Forest, two packages that are not part of the standard Weka 3.7 package.

Per http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager%3F, I understand that to call non-standard packages, *(after first loading them using the package manager)* I should envoke the **weka.Run** command. If I want to envoke ADTree, on the labor dataset that comes with Weka, I can do so with the following code:

> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run ADTree -t weka/data/labor.arff

Similarly, if I want to envoke a Rotation Forest, this code works:

> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run RotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff

However, I'm not sure how to wrap the two algorithms together.

I can, say, wrap J48 in RotationForest:

> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run RotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48

But I'm not sure how to call ADTree after calling Rotation Forest.  Neither of the following work:

> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run RotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff weka.Run ADTree
>
> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run RotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff -W weka.Run ADTree
>
> java -cp weka/weka.jar weka.Run RotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff -W weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheepishly, I continued my Googling and found the solution here: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?152334-WEKA-RotationForest-by-comman-line-is-not-working!

Basically, I needed to start my syntax with:

> java -cp wekafiles/packages/alternatingDecisionTrees/alternatingDecisionTrees.jar:wekafiles/packages/rotationForest/rotationForest.jar:weka/weka.jar

or

> java -cp [path-to-package_1] : [path-to-package_2] : [path-to-weka.jar]

Then, I can envoke **weka.classifiers.meta.rotationForest** and **weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree** and go forward:

> java -cp wekafiles/packages/alternatingDecisionTrees/alternatingDecisionTrees.jar:wekafiles/packages/rotationForest/rotationForest.jar:weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.rotationForest -t weka/data/labor.arff -W weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree

I'll leave this post open in case someone else might find it helpful.